# Bash script to modify and zip files

Tags: bash, perl

I am trying to write a script that zips up some files. However, in some of the files, I need to update a path to a dependency.

The script to zip up the files currently looks like this;

```
#!/bin/sh

for APP in "${APPS[@]}"
do
  cd app/${APP}
  npm install
  zip -r ../../test.zip node_modules
  zip -uj ../../test.zip src/*.js
  cd ../../

  zip -uj test.zip app/utils/*.js
done
```

In `src/*.js` there are imports like this;

`const someUtil = require('../../utils/someUtil')`

Whilst zipping these files, I need to change the utils path from `../../utils/` to `./`, but I do not want to change the path in the original file.

I have been able to update the path in the original file like this;

`perl -pi -e 's/..\/..\/utils\//.\//g' src/*.js`

How could I go about only modifying the file that is to be zipped?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you want to zip a changed content of files, but not change the files themselves.

Since you do this from a shell script it is simple to write new, changed, files with Perl and zip those (`source/*.js_tmp` below), then remove them.

```
perl -we'while (<>) { 
    open $fh, ">${ARGV}_tmp" if eof;
    print $fh s{../../utils}{/.}gr;
}' source/*.js
```

The [`<>` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) reads lines from all submitted files. A new file is opened when [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) detects the last line in a file (or unopened filehandle), with the name derived from the current [$ARGV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV). The `/r` modifier in regex makes `s/` operator return the modified string instead of changing it in place.

Or, using [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm)

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -we'
    path("${_}_tmp")->spew( path($_)->slurp =~ s{../../utils}{./}gr ) for @ARGV
' source/*.js
```

The module is extremely handy and worth a quick installation.

Both commands above write out changed files as `source/*.js_tmp`, for simplicity. Make these temporary filenames so to not overwrite anything. Or, use the original names in a new, temporary directory that the shell script can make and then remove.

Another, perhaps simpler, way is to make a temporary directory and copy all files to it in the shell script, then run your exact Perl one-liner on that. Then zip them and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The perl `i` option makes perl edit the files in-place, which is not what you want here. I don't know perl, but I do know sed, which is similar for this use case, and is more lightweight:

```sh
mkdir --parents to-be-zipped/src
for f in src/*.js; do
  sed -e 's/..\/..\/utils\//.\//g' $f >to-be-zipped/$f
done
```

Then the modified files to be zipped will be in a directory called `to-be-zipped`. If that is not a suitable place, you can move them using `mv` or output them to a different place.

Alternatively, simply copy your entire project to a directory on a temporary filesystem (ideally a ramdisk), modify the files there, zip them and then delete the temporary copy.